# Replace the text of whole column it contains specific string mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a question in mysql about searching the column in a table and if it contains specific string replace whole column with particular text.
Lets say If the column containing this text`data/variant_image/2/IW_HH_1B_sxph-2o_l7ar-4r_kh2k-fd.jpg` has this string in it`IW_HH_1B_` then replace it with  `data/variant_image/1/IW_HH_1B.jpg`

I tried update,replace functions but it didnt work. And searching on google returns only replacing that particular string option. but not complete column text.

Comment: Is this string that you are looking for always going to be 'IW_HH_1B_'? Does the value of any column that contains this string has to always be changed to 'data/variant_image/1/IW_HH_1B.jpg'?

Comment: Well in the table `IW_HH_1B.jpg` is the image name for one image and different products use same image. Instead of giving link for that image what happened was they copied the image and each time image got copied it added _ + 5 digits to the image name. So to remove multiple copies, I am searching for that base name(of the first image) and and changing links for all other images and setting it as first image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple update works:

```
UPDATE your_table
    SET your_column = 'data/variant_image/1/IW_HH_1B.jpg'
    WHERE your_column LIKE '%IW_HH_1B_%'
```

Comment: Sorry My bad! I got it working. I was trying various things and it turned out to be simple. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional update for that:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = 'data/variant_image/1/IW_HH_1B.jpg'
WHERE LOCATE('IW_HH_1B' COLLATE utf8_bin, columnname) > 0
```

If you want it to be case insensitive leaf the collate part out.